# Security Exception while running an ASP.NET on deployment server

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to run a WebAPI on a deployment server connected via a Remote Desktop link, but when I try to connect to the website via a browser, I get the error of:

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.

I can run and access the website fine when it is running from Visual Studio, its just when it is on the deployment server.

So far, I have tried:

- Adding a `<trust level="Full" />` element to `web.config`
- Place the site in its own application pool in IIS (It already was).
- [The information in this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555466)
- Made changes to my code to see if it was the code itself which was causing the issue (I don't think it was, any request method such as POST and GET returned the same issue as above. I even tried other directories/URLs, I still got the error.)
- Remove and re-publish the site several times.

Is there something which I am doing wrong which I'm not realising? Is there another way which I can solve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tell the issue to hosting company which hosts your app. I experienced same problem and it was not about web.config file or trust level. The hosting company that I work explained me they changed control panels from cpanel to plesk. And it solved my problem.

Comment: Well I'd love it to be that easy but the hosting company is myself!